# Error: [$injector:undef] is occurring in service angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Am getting an error `Error: [$injector:undef]` when am using service and http. I couldn't find why is it coming after changing all the changes that has been suggested for this particular error. Kindly check the below code

```js
mainApp.controller('deviceDataController',["$scope","mainService", function ($scope,mainService) {
                console.log(mainService);
                mainService.deviceDataVar().success(function (data) {
                   // $scope.deviceDetails = mainService.devices;
                   console.log(data);
                });
            }]);
            
                
            mainApp.factory("mainService",["$http", function ($http) {

                angular.forEach(deviceIds, function(value, key) {
                    var timezone = user_response.timezone;
                    var DataUrl = LAX_API + "device_info.php?deviceid=" + value + "&limit=288&timezone=" + timezone;

                    return {
                        deviceDataVar: function () {
                           return $http.get(DataUrl).success(function (response) {
                                devices = response.data;
                                return devices;
                            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                // log error
                                console.log(data)
                            });;
                        }
                    }

                });
            }]);
```

kindly help me out with my issue

Thanks!!

Comment: Your factory code is invalid, Factoy should return only public methods, you are creating them inside a forEach loop. It is correct code, or invalid copy-paste?

Comment: this is the correct code..when i console inside the loop i get the value but could not return it.

Comment: So in a nutshell you want to call more thna one AJAX calls, for each deviceId and agregate all results into one list? How many elements deviceIds has?

Comment: 2 value max which is a dynamic value. yes i need to call for both the values.

Comment: I've figured that out:) I've created a sample code, that could help you with your problem, with some description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory declaration is not valid.

1. Your factory should return only single method
2. Create a method that returns $http promises
3. Agregate all promises inside $q, that will wait for all of them to return a response
4. Agregate all responses
5. Return them inside a promise- you cannot return a value, because AJAX calls are async.

Your factory should look like this:

```
      mainApp.factory("mainService", function ($http, $q) {
                /* generate single link for deviceID */
                function getDevice(value){
                   var timezone = user_response.timezone;
                   var dataUrl= LAX_API + "device_info.php?deviceid=" + value + "&limit=288&timezone=" + timezone; 
                   return $http.get(dataUrl);
                 }

                function deviceDataVar(){
                   // map method will transform list of deviceIds into a list of $http promises
                   var allRequests = deviceIds.map(getDevice);
                   // this promise will wait for all calls to end, then return a list of their results
                   $q.all(allRequests).then(function(arrayOfResults) { 
                   // here you will have all responses, you just need to agregate them into single collection.
                   // secondly you will need to wrap them into a promise and return
                   return ...
                 });

               }

                  /* Return only public methods, at the end */
                return {
                    deviceDataVar: deviceDataVar
                }
        });
```

(I was writing this on fly, so there could be few mistakes :), but the conception is right though )

Useful links:

1. Aggregating promises: [angular -- accessing data of multiple http calls - how to resolve the promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545573/angular-accessing-data-of-multiple-http-calls-how-to-resolve-the-promises)
2. Array.prototype.map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
3. How to apss a promise to a factory: [How can I pass back a promise from a service in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001400/how-can-i-pass-back-a-promise-from-a-service-in-angularjs)

**UPDATE**:

To make it work by invokiing small steps you should :

1. Mock the factory method, let it return a hardcoded value. Return it through a promise.
2. replace hardcoded value with single (hardcoded) URL to a selected device.
3. use aggregation ($q.all) for this single $http call.
4. replace single $http with array made from deviceIds list.

Comment: It shows you the concept, it may contain few syntax bugs, due to no IDE near me:) I would advise to do it step by stemp, do not implement whole code at start, because it is complicated:)

Comment: am getting error TypeError: angular.map is not a function on searching regarding google is suggesting angular google map

Comment: @user2590035 my bad:) map is a javascript function :) will add some refs

Comment: yeah plz.. I am out of idea's with this.

Comment: I've added few points, you should do it step by step, then you could work it out:)